# ¿por qué no reconoce las variables por POST en php?

Tags: php, post

Cuando quiero ejecutar este php me arroja el error de que las variables no estan definidas, aun imprimiendo un var_dump a las variable me regresa un NULL

```
<?php

    include 'db_config.php';

    $con = mysqli_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
    
    if( isset($usuario) && isset($contrasena) )
    {
            $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM `tb_usuarios` WHERE `usuario` = '".$usuario."' AND `contrasena` = '".$contrasena."'";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sqlQuery))
    {

        $result["estado"] = TRUE;
        $result["mensaje"] = "Bienvenido!";

    }
    else
    {
        $result["estado"] = FALSE;
        $result["mensaje"] = "Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecta";
    }
    }
    else
    {
        $result["estado"] = FALSE;
        $result["mensaje"] = "Error en las Variables";   
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    print(json_encode($result));

?>
```

Comment: Su las variables POST no estan regresando nada, lo más probable es que no se le esten asignando primero. A espera del codigo de todos modos

Comment: Para depurar, ve al orígen, en este caso, haz un `var_dump($_POST);` y revisa lo que muestra.

Comment: Pues si están NULL, no estás enviándolas. Cómo le estás entregando el mensaje POST a este script PHP?

Comment: Estas seguro de que la pagina es llamada a través de un formulario con método POST, de lo contrario no estará asignado. A los inputs y elementos de formulario asegurate de tenga el atributo name. De todas formas yo comprobaría el POST con algo como isset($_POST['usuario']) de que no es nula y darle un valor por defecto a $usuario